# I dont know answer the question, could anybody help me?

Tags: translation, meaning

[image]

I dont know answer the question, could anybody help me?

Comment: The highlighted entry reads "Security question (please ignore if you haven't set it up)"—I assume that means that you can't select a security question upon login if you didn't set one up when you registered.

Answer (score 1):

This means you need to set a security question to protect your QQ account. QQ is a social media and it's easy to be hacked, set a security question can help you find your account back.